# Is there an equivalent to "optimize" that allows duplicates to be removed from an unmanaged table in Spark Databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I would like to remove duplicated rows from an unmanaged table in spark. **I know there are commands like** `df.dropduplicates()` **that work on dataframes** but is there a command that can do the same for the underlying data?

So for instance optimise works like so:
`spark.sql("OPTIMIZE <TABLE>")`

is there an equivalent with something like:
`spark.sql("DELETE DUPLICATES <TABLE>")`

Comment: Is this Databricks specific question ?

Comment: @Sanket9394 apologies, potentially, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is is *not*.

A delta table needs an appropriate SQL clause for a DELETE.

For inspiration see https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/remove+duplicates+in+sql

Vacuum periodically is required for the real physical deletions.

You can of course use MERGE when loading to obviate subsequent deletions.

The question has nothing to do with pyspark or unmanaged / managed tables.